# How to get particular object from jsonb in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I  have a table called 'Test' that holds two fields 'qnId' and 'Answers'.
'qnId' stores a uuid and 'Answers' is a jsonb array that roughly looks like this:

```
[{ "user" : "1", "ans" : "some text" }, { "user" : "3", "ans": "some text"}]
```

how can I retrieve the value of `"ans"` of `"user"` with value `3`.
How can I retrieve the value using normal SQL queries

Comment: This, in fact, is not valid json: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=7515077cca28d8873c600c3179f404ea You simply list JSON objects in an JSON object. But listing objects can only be done within JSON arrays. Otherwise you would need a key/value construct

Comment: The JSON format is edited, I think it is valid now - S-Man

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=28a6a618bc6e885df845fca4fa8d7dc4)

You can use `jsonb_array_elements()` to expand the array elements into one row each. Afterwards you are able to filter the right elements using the `->>` operator ([documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html)):

```
SELECT
    uuid,
    elements ->> 'ans'
FROM
    mytable,
    jsonb_array_elements(answers) elements
WHERE 
    elements ->> 'user' = '3'
```

Answer (score 2):

try something like this:

```
select
    x ->> 'ans' as user_3_ans
from
    jsonb_array_elements('[{ "user" : "1", "ans" : "some text 1" }, { "user" : "3", "ans": "some text 3"}]'::jsonb) as x
where
    x ->> 'user' = '3'
```

same, but from table:

```
with

table1 as (
    select
        1 as id,
        '[{ "user" : "1", "ans" : "some text 1" }, { "user" : "3", "ans": "some text 3"}]'::jsonb as answers
)

select
    id,
    answers,
    el ->> 'ans' as user_3_ans
from
    (   select
            id,
            answers,
            jsonb_array_elements(answers) as el
        from
            table1) as x
where
    el ->> 'user' = '3'
```

Comment: Thanks, Y K for the answer but in this, you are explicitly giving JSON data to json_array_elements(). But how can I get those JSON data from the database and pass to that function

Comment: @Manu are you sure about the syntax of answers column's values which start with double curly braces `{{` and end with `}}` ..?

Comment: yes the syntax is like {{json},{json}} - Barbaros Ozhan

Comment: I have one more doubt what should be my data type of Answers column, jsonb or jsonb[], I am confused. I need to add multiple JSON objects to that column.                         In the above answer Y K is already using jsonb as the type and adding multiple JSON objects, so what is the difference between jsonb and jsonb[].

Comment: @Manu The difference: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=565708fb69da3d65752e6efae9e55619 Your column type is jsonb. This can contain every valid JSON string no matter if it is a simple JSON object (`{"a:b"}`) or an JSON array (`["a", "b"]`). More specific: You can think of simply holding a text, that can be interpreted in some way. A type jsonb[] aggregates many of these texts into a Postgres array. This array has nothing to do with JSON and cannot be parsed as such