# Error while getting particular object from jsonb in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, postgresql-9.5, node-postgres

I have created a table  :

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
    uuid int,
    answers jsonb
);
```

Inserted some JSON values and id :

```
   db.query('insert into mytable(uuid,answers) values($1,$2::jsonb)',
            [1,{ "user" : "1", "ans" : "Answer of 1" }])
```

I am using node js and pg as a client for Postgres.

The data is successfully entered and return the row as expected.

```
SELECT answers FROM mytable 
{"ans": "Answer of 1","user": "1"}
```

But when I tried to retrieve the value of "ans" of "user" with value 1,
it returned an error:

```
SELECT
    elements ->> 'ans'
FROM
    mytable,
    jsonb_array_elements(answers) elements
WHERE 
    elements ->> 'user' = '1'
```

```
ERROR:  cannot extract elements from an object
SQL state: 22023
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57339793/how-to-get-particular-object-from-jsonb-in-postgresql?noredirect=1&lq=1) you inserted an JSON array: `[{...}, {...}]`. Now, the result set of your `SELECT` statement seems that you inserted a simple object: `{...}`. Of course then you cannot call `jsonb_array_elements()` which is for JSON arrays: [demo with array](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=5323091ffd3a57b146cdd10c33e3416f), [demo without array](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=31f51935fd8d3debafdb45c8d6c8a3d9).

So, if you want to insert an JSON array, you need adjust your input parameter by adding the array braces around your JSON object: `[...]`.

If you do not want to insert an array but a simple JSON object then you can go with this query which saves you the step for expanding the array. You can call the objects directly:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=cd398f082816bdb25d72cd789bbafe77)

```
SELECT
    uuid,
    answers ->> 'ans'
FROM
    mytable
WHERE 
    answers ->> 'user' = '1'
```

Answer (score 2):

Hoping, I understood your question correctly.

Please check below query.

```
SELECT
    answers ->> 'ans'
FROM
    mytable
where answers ->> 'user' = '1'
;
```